# TSQL Average sales query

Tags: t-sql

i am trying to run a query to report back the average sales for the past 6 weeks, and also display each weeks sales along with a total.

I have managed to do the total sales so far but struggling with an Average and each weeks sales.

Any help would be much apprecaited.

Below is what i have so far:

```
Declare @Branch as Int
Set @Branch = 4

Select
cu.[branch],
cu.[cust_code],
cu.[business_name],
cu.[contact_name],
cu.[post_code],
cu.[account_status],
cu.[date_opened],
SUM (th.[total_value]) as 'Total_Sales'

FROM [dbo].[customer] as cu
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[transaction_header] as th on cu.branch = th.branch and cu.cust_code = th.cust_code
WHERE cu.[branch] = @Branch
and th.[orderinvoiced] > DATEADD(week, -6, GetDate())

GROUP BY cu.[branch],cu.[cust_code],cu.[business_name],cu.[contact_name],cu.[post_code],cu.[account_status],cu.[date_opened]
order by Total_Sales asc
```

Comment: You will need 2 separate queries for "grouping by-week" vs "summary/avg for 6 weeks".  You also need to decide what is "a week". Is it "Sun-Sat" or "every 7 days" because those are different queries.

Comment: @tgolisch i think ideally a week would be sun-sat

I have added the below now
SUM (CASE WHEN th.[orderinvoiced] > DATEADD(week, -1, GetDate()) then th.[total_value] END) as 'Week 1',
SUM (CASE WHEN th.[orderinvoiced] > DATEADD(week, -2, GetDate()) then th.[total_value]) END) as 'Week 2'

But obviously week 2 is totaling the whole two weeks not just the second week in isolation. I guess also this isnt using sun-sat.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I'm also unclear about what you mean by "average sales". Does that mean "total per-day, averaged for the week" or some different sum divided over a different interval.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query: Total Sales and average (total per week). You probably don't need customer info in this. I expect your average should roll-up the customer records, unless you want to report by-customer too.

```
Declare @Branch as Int
Set @Branch = 4

SELECT SUM(th.[total_value]) as [Total_Sales], SUM(th.[total_value])/6 as [Avg_Sales_Per_Week]
FROM [dbo].[customer] as cu
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[transaction_header] as th on cu.branch = th.branch and cu.cust_code = th.cust_code
WHERE cu.[branch] = @Branch
   and th.[orderinvoiced] > DATEADD(week, -6, GetDate())
```

Next: The same summary, by week

```
Declare @Branch as Int
Set @Branch = 4

SELECT DatePart(week, th.transaction_date) as sales_week, 
   SUM(th.[total_value]) as [Total_Sales_Weekly], 
   SUM(th.[total_value])/7 as [Avg_Sales_Per_Day]
FROM [dbo].[customer] as cu
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[transaction_header] as th on cu.branch = th.branch and cu.cust_code = th.cust_code
WHERE cu.[branch] = @Branch
   and th.[orderinvoiced] > DATEADD(week, -6, GetDate())
GROUP BY DatePart(Week, th.Transaction_Date)
```

I'm taking a guess that your `transaction_header` table must have a `transaction_date` column (or equiv).  The `DatePart(week, ...)` function is probably what you were missing. It calculates the "week of the year" an so you can roll-up your data into weeks Sun-Sat (or whatever your SQL server has configured).